# How to pass optional parameters in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

This is a wrapper function for Invoke-WebRequest (I have removed a lot of extra functionality to keep the noise down)

```
function Invoke-SERVERAPI($apiFolder, $adminCredentials, [ValidateSet("GET","POST","PUT","DELETE")]  $HTTPmethod, $contentType, $body, $verbose)
{
    $resp1HTTPCode= 'Not set'
    try
    {
        if ( ($HTTPmethod -eq 'GET') -or ($HTTPmethod -eq 'DELETE'))
        {
            $resp1 = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $apiFolder -Method $HTTPmethod -Credential $adminCredentials -ContentType $contentType -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Verbose:$verbose
        }
        else
        {
            $resp1 = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $apiFolder -Body $body -Method $HTTPmethod -Credential $adminCredentials -ContentType $contentType -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Verbose:$verbose
        }
        $resp1HTTPCode = $resp1.StatusCode

    }
    catch [Exception]
    {
        $resp1HTTPCode = $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.Value__

    }

    return $resp1HTTPCode
}
```

I need to pass -body parameter on verb POST and PUT but don't pass it in GET and DELETE. I managed to do it with an IF/ELSE.

**Is there a better way to achieve this in PowerShell like I did in the switch parameter -Verbose?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it involves forming a hashtable with parameters and using that instead or in addition of parameter list, aka [splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx). In your case, you do like this:

```
try
{
    $ifbody=@{}
    if ( ($HTTPmethod -eq 'PUT') -or ($HTTPmethod -eq 'POST'))
    {
        $ifbody."Body"=$body
    }
    $resp1 = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $apiFolder @ifbody -Method $HTTPmethod -Credential $adminCredentials -ContentType $contentType -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Verbose:$verbose

    $resp1HTTPCode = $resp1.StatusCode

}
```

The `@ifbody` reverts the hashtable into `-key=value -key2=value2...` sequence of parameters to a cmdlet or a function.

Answer (score 4):

You should have a look at `ParameterSetName` in [about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx). It can help you to differentiate different sets of parameters.

Comment: Is there a way to separate parameter set by the value of one parameter? Say here, `if ( ($HTTPmethod -eq 'GET') -or ($HTTPmethod -eq 'DELETE'))` there would be one parameter set, and if two others, another.